# How to expose locally dockerized postgres service to the net

Tags: postgresql, docker, ngrok, docker-cloud, fly

**Context:**

I'm building a full stack project and have decided to deploy my services on docker, I have 3 services at the moment, `database-service`, `frontend-service`, and `backend-service`, in addition to `postgres` and `pgadmin`.

I have set up a docker-compose file and have ran all the services.

But, at some point, I have added Prisma to my `database-service` and some Prisma-Docker-Apple Silicon problems have started to prevent me from build and running my `database-service` in the localhost.

What I decided is to build my docker image for `database-service` on the cloud, at `fly.io`.

**The Issue:**

As I said before, I have decided to work with Prisma on my database-service, so in my `prisma.yml`, I should provide my postgres link. I have tried to expose my 5432 port to the internet using ngrok, but it didn't work.

If you have encountered a similar issue, please let me know how you could resolve this conflict. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ngrok tcp 5432`, and not `ngrok http 5432`.

I've started a PosgreSQL using `docker run --name so75297011 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=so75297011 -d -p 5432:5432 postgres:latest`. Don't forget about the ports when running PostgreSQL in Docker!

And exposed it via ngrok: `ngrok tcp 5432`. Got a tunnel: `tcp://0.tcp.eu.ngrok.io:10821 -> localhost:5432`.

Here is the result, connection successful

[image]